# AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant:afterProjectsRead() update then re-read poms

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

Is there any Maven API I to re-read the pom files again.

I have a Maven extension like below (*see `TODO`*):

```
    @Component(role = AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant.class, hint = "update")
    public class UpdateExtension extends AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant {

        @Override
        public void afterProjectsRead(MavenSession session) throws MavenExecutionException {

            for (MavenProject project : projects) {
                File pomFile = project.getFile();

                // Update pomFile version and certain dependency versions
            }

            // TODO Get Maven to read the project pom files again
        }

        @Override
        public void afterSessionStart(MavenSession session) throws MavenExecutionException {}

        @Override
        public void afterSessionEnd(MavenSession session) throws MavenExecutionException {}
    }
```

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: I want something like this plugin 
https://github.com/jgitver/maven-external-version-jgitver
But I need to update the pom version and its parent version based on the git branch name. Say change 1.0-SNAPSHOT to 1.0-featurex-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Take a look here: http://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

Comment: héhé, I'm doing EXACTLY the same thing at the moment: reusing the jgitver plugin to update the version as you described (using branch name). I'll keep you updated !